# What is the probability of Adam being first in line or Beth being at the end of the line if each probability is 1 / n?

Tags: probability, permutations

Given this type of problem, it's safe to assume there is a 1 in n chance of Adam being first because there are n students total, including Beth. To me, that means if we are doing a permutation, there are n! possible ways to arrange all the students including Adam and Beth, (n - 1)! ways to arrange the students if you pick Adam to be first, (n - 1)! ways to arrange the students if you pick Beth last, and (n - 2)! ways to arrange the students if you pick Adam first and Beth last, which you must subtract to remove duplicate permutations from one of the above ways where Adam is picked to be first or Beth is picked to be last.

In total, the probability is as follows: $$\frac{2(n - 1)! - (n - 2)!}{n!} = \frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$$.

However, we can also think of it as $P(A)$ means the probability that Adam is first in line, which is $\Large{\frac{1}{n}}$, and that $P(B)$ means the probability that Beth is last, which is also $\Large{\frac{1}{n}}$. Knowing this, we can say the following: $$P(A\ or\ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\ and\ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B)=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}$$

This is where I get confused. My two probabilities don't equal: $$\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\neq\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Where am I going wrong? Is it with the first method of using permutations, the second method using laws of probability, or do I just need to use algebra to manipulate these two expressions into equivalent forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember first that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

$P(A) = P(B) = \frac{1}{n}$

Now, your second answer was wrong because you assumed they were independent, aka $P(B | A) = P(B)$. In reality, the generalized solution is:

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) * P(B | A)$

Now let's say A is Adam being first in line and B is Beth being last. If Adam is first in line, there are only $n - 1$ spots Beth can be in, so:

$P(B | A) = \frac{1}{n-1}$

So final probability:

$P(A\cup B) = \frac{2}{n} - \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$

Comment: Oh I see. The probability that Beth is last isn't $\frac{1}{n}$ anymore, because we are assuming if both events are true, Adam has already been placed, which means there are only $n-1$ places remaining for Beth to be in, indeed changing the problem. Thanks for clearing that up and I'm glad the my reasoning with the permutation wasn't off.